# unknown control 'rotate'

Tags: pi-4, raspicam, picamera, libcamera

I have recently purchased a Raspberry Pi Camera Rev 1.3, and I'm trying to rotate it to 90 degrees, then its not able to rotate. Its just rotating it to 0 degrees or 180 degrees below is the command that I have used.

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=rotate=90
unknown control 'rotate'

libcamera-hello --rotate 90
unknown control 'rotate'
```

It's working normally with 7 inch screen but I'm unable to rotate it. I don't  know what  wrong did I did.

Comment: how do you rotate to 0, and to 180?

Comment: `v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls` shows the permitted controls.  What is your question?

Comment: @joan no results on this command but on `v4l2-ctl --list-ctrl` there is a list